# Antisamy 1.5.3 span tag style attribute exception

Tags: java, html, antisamy

I am using antisamy 1.5.3 along with following dependencies

1. batik-1.5-fop-0.20-5.jar
2. nekohtml-1.9.6.jar
3. xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar

Hi I have an input html string

```
str = "<p><ul>
              <li><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.4em;\">Sample Output</span></li>
          </ul>
       </p>"
```

I expect the output from antisamy to be the same. But I get following exception, can someone tell me where I am going wrong and is there a workaround for this issue.

```
ERROR:  ''
org.owasp.validator.html.ScanException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.owasp.validator.html.scan.AntiSamySAXScanner.scan(AntiSamySAXScanner.java:135)
    at org.owasp.validator.html.AntiSamy.scan(AntiSamy.java:101)
    at com.tibbr.antisamy.TibbrAntisamy.getCleancontent(TibbrAntisamy.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:470)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:328)
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:71)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:202)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallTwoArgNode.interpret(CallTwoArgNode.java:59)
    at org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:224)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:119)
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:188)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_EVAL(ASTInterpreter.java:96)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.evalWithBinding(ASTInterpreter.java:175)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.evalCommon(RubyKernel.java:1103)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.eval(RubyKernel.java:1061)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by updating the dependent jar for antisamy.jar
the dependent jars are as follows

1. xercesImpl.jar
2. xml-apis.jar
3. nekohtml.jar
4. sac.jar
5. commons-httpclient-3.1.jar